# ¿Como obtener las lineas de texto que contengan texto especifico en archivo con sentencias SQL con Expresion Regular?

Tags: regex, archivo

Tengo un archivo que contiene sentencias SQL, son alrededor  de 2,500 líneas. Necesito extraer todas las lineas que contengan el texto entre la sentencia "THEN" y el primer paréntesis abierto "(" en todas las líneas.

```
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '36' THEN
/*Invocación de BANCASAT*/
/*CAMBIO 13.0 XXXXXX 05/05/2015 PAGO DE SERVICIOS CON TC */
IF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (1, 2) THEN
pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio( lc_cuenta 
,lc_tipo_cuenta 
,lc_monto 
,lc_codproveedor 
,lc_numtransac 
,lc_dato1 
,lc_dato2 
,lc_dato3
,lc_dato4
,lc_dato5
,tn_error 
,tu_xml_salida);
ELSIF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (4) THEN --TC
pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio_tc( lc_cuenta
,lc_monto 
,lc_codproveedor
,lc_numtransac
,lc_dato1 
,lc_dato2 
,lc_dato3 
,lc_dato4 
,lc_dato5 
,tn_error 
,tu_xml_salida);
END IF;
--INICIO V43.0
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '37' THEN
BE.pk_ebantrabpr.obtener_destino_prestamo(tn_error, tu_xml_salida); 
--FIN V43.0
/* Cambio 15 x KFRM 20091013 */
-- V.30.0 inicio trama busca estatus actual de la cuenta RM-GGP-040
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '38' THEN
be.pk_ebantrabser.prcd_eban_estatus_cta( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida);
-- V.30.0 fin trama busca estatus actual de la cuenta RM-GGP-040
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '39' THEN
pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_reposicion_tc( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,lc_moneda1 ,--LG_AGENCIA,
lc_agencia ,lc_dato1 ,lc_dato2 ,lc_dato3 ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida ,lc_codproveedor);
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '40' THEN
pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_solicitud_tc( lc_dato1 ,lc_dato2 ,lc_dato3 ,lc_dato4 ,lc_dato5 ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida ,lc_codproveedor);
```

Básicamente necesito este texto de todas las lineas:

```
THEN IF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (
THEN BE.pk_ebantrabpr.obtener_destino_prestamo(
```

Utilizando esta expresión :

```
(THEN)([^(]*)
```

[He llegado a esta solución](https://regexr.com/535vi)

Pero necesito refinar la expresión regular para evitar el texto que se encuentre comentado ya sea por "/* */", o por "--" entre la sentencia "THEN" y el primer paracentesis.

Como puedo ajustar la expresión regular para lograr esto?

Comment: De ese texto ¿Extraes solo esas 2 líneas?; ¿Que pasa con las líneas como `THEN --TC`y su línea posterior?. ¿En todas las líneas comentadas `/*`y `*/` abren y cierran en la misma línea?. Lo primero es remover las líneas comentadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edite para aclarar que trabajo con el sistema operativo Ubuntu. 
Use varios pasos y varias herramientas separadas por tubería para llegar al resultado. Al final obtuve más de dos líneas, basándome en el archivo de muestra.

```
sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo |grep -A1 'THEN' |sed -E ':a;N;/\nELSIF/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D' |sed 's/THEN/\nTHEN /g' |awk -F'(' '/THEN/ {print $1"("}'
```

Veamos los los pasos uno a uno
`sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo` 
Elimina las líneas comentadas.
`sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo | grep -A1 'THEN'` 
Imprime todas las líneas que contienen la palabra THEN y la línea posterior
`sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo | grep -A1 'THEN'  |sed -E ':a;N;/\nELSIF/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D'` 
Agrupa todas las líneas en base a las que empiezan por **ELSIF**
En este punto la salida es:

```
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '36' THEN   IF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (1, 2) THEN    pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio( lc_cuenta    --
ELSIF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (4) THEN --TC   pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio_tc( lc_cuenta --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '37' THEN   BE.pk_ebantrabpr.obtener_destino_prestamo(tn_error, tu_xml_salida);     --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '38' THEN   be.pk_ebantrabser.prcd_eban_estatus_cta( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida);   --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '39' THEN   pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_reposicion_tc( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,lc_moneda1 ,--LG_AGENCIA, --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '40' THEN   pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_solicitud_tc( lc_dato1 ,lc_dato2 ,lc_dato3 ,lc_dato4 ,lc_dato5 ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida ,lc_codproveedor);
```

`sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo | grep -A1 'THEN'  |sed -E ':a;N;/\nELSIF/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D' |sed 's/THEN/\nTHEN /g'` 
Agrega un salto de línea delante de la palabra **THEN**, esto importante porque hasta el paso anterior hay una línea que contiene 2 **THEN** 
La salida en este paso es:

```
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '36' 
THEN    IF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (1, 2) 
THEN    pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio( lc_cuenta    --
ELSIF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (4) 
THEN  --TC  pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio_tc( lc_cuenta --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '37' 
THEN    BE.pk_ebantrabpr.obtener_destino_prestamo(tn_error, tu_xml_salida);     --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '38' 
THEN    be.pk_ebantrabser.prcd_eban_estatus_cta( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida);   --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '39' 
THEN    pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_reposicion_tc( lc_tipo_cuenta ,lc_cuenta ,lc_moneda1 ,--LG_AGENCIA, --
ELSIF lc_codigo_trama = '40' 
THEN    pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_solicitud_tc( lc_dato1 ,lc_dato2 ,lc_dato3 ,lc_dato4 ,lc_dato5 ,tn_error ,tu_xml_salida ,lc_codproveedor);
```

**Finalmente:**
`sed '/^\/\*.*\*\/$/d' archivo |grep -A1 'THEN' |sed -E ':a;N;/\nELSIF/!s/\n/\t/;ta;P;D' |sed 's/THEN/\nTHEN /g' |awk -F'(' '/THEN/ {print $1"("}'` 
Imprime solo las líneas que contienen la palabra THEN y usa `(` como separador, imprimiendo el primer campo y añadiedo un `(` al final.

```
THEN    IF lc_tipo_cuenta IN (
THEN    pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio(
THEN  --TC  pk_ebantrabbancasat.pago_servicio_tc(
THEN    BE.pk_ebantrabpr.obtener_destino_prestamo(
THEN    be.pk_ebantrabser.prcd_eban_estatus_cta(
THEN    pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_reposicion_tc(
THEN    pk_ebantrabser.prc_eban_solicitud_tc(
```

Comment: Me parece una elegante y brillante solución... Gracias.